# Getting White Space While on both side Printing the Word file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, printing, documents

I tying to use margin 0 page.
While I am editing there is no problem.
After printing the document to PDF there some white space left over. How to remove those white space.

Margin: 0;

Page-size: A4 (8.27 X 11.69);

See the pictures for better understanding.

[image: Document while editing]

[image: Printing Configuration]

[image: Printed Document PDF]

Comment: How do you generate the blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you created the blue half. In my tests, I do not get a white border when I

- use a shape that overlaps the page border and print to PDF, **OR**
- use a blue page background and Save As (not print to) PDF

You can put the blue shape into the header, so you can still write text on the page.

If you use a blue background, you can use white shapes in the header to create the white part of the page.

[image]

Note that there is still a very thin white border, but not a wide one like in your screenshot.